# Make SlidingLayer occupy full screen

Tags: android, sliding, android-sliding

Implementing the SlidingLayer guthub library in my activity, wherein I am able to get the layer to open and close, but it only consumes the area of the activity upto it's previous sibling in the overall layout container.

Meaning, if my overall layout is like this -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_background">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/npTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:background="@drawable/title" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/viewSwitch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/GetL"
                        android:layout_width="165dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/getL"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/LF"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/lf"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >
                    </View>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/att"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/att"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ld"
                        android:layout_width="165dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/ld"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/swipeForNextPage"
                        android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/rightHandPointer"
                        android:src="@drawable/hand_pointer_right" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ky"
                        android:layout_width="165dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/ky"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/rep"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/rep"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >
                    </View>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/har"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/har"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/co"
                        android:layout_width="165dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
                        android:text="@string/co"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/leftHandPointer"
                        android:src="@drawable/hand_pointer_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/swipeForPrevPage"
                        android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hideableLinear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/help"
                style="@style/StylishButton"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                android:background="@drawable/final_red_help_aqua_button" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/moreoptionsclickarea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/moreleftarrow"
                    style="@style/StylishButton"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:background="@drawable/double_arrow_red_up"
                    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/moreoptions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:text="@string/moreoptions"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/morerightarrow"
                style="@style/StylishButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:background="@drawable/double_arrow_red_up" />
                -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com....SlidingLayer
            android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/activity_background" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:onClick="buttonClicked"
                android:text="test button" />
        </com....SlidingLayer>
</FrameLayout>
```

The slidinglayerview now consumes all the space from the bottom of the activity to the top right away on activity load. Everything else is gone.

I would like the newly sliding layer to consume the whole activity screen only once the button is clicked.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `LinearLayout` in a `FrameLayout` and move the `SlidingLayerView` outside:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
    <SlidingLayerView />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Updated the question with actual xml being used. Now the sliding layer consumes all the activity space. Not what I wanted. I know, I must be messing up some properties on the xml, but not sure what. Pls help.

Comment: Why are you not just using a `DrawerLayout` instead of some obscure "SlidingLayer"? I would assume that they do very similar things.

Comment: DrawerLayout provided by Google only obscures d current activity wid the expanded Drawer section something like FB drawers open from left and right. I need the current activity to be almost completely obscured with my new section opening up from below.  Actually I'm able to do this using your suggested FrameLayout, but somehow when the SlidingLayer renders, it renders the whole activity blank initially, wherein the button underneath it (to open the sliding layer) even though invisible is still somehow clickable. And when clicked, does open the layer. Pretty weird. Works fine next time onwards.

Comment: If you care to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can probably help you further. The problem is probably not in the layout.